# why is my updatepanel generate hundreds of script block?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I have an asp.net web form with a repeater. In this repeater is multiple controls and I affect to these controls javascript functions with the ItemCreated event. I made this with this kind of code:

```
btnBareme.OnClientClick = string.Format("ChangeBareme('{0}','{1}',this); return false", item.Num_dossier, item.IdDemande);
```

The javascript function "changeBareme()" is defined in the header of the page. It is working fine but i need to update the repeater independently from the other elements of the page.

So I surround the repeater with a asp:UpdatePanel. Something like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePnl2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>
              <h1>Foo</h1>                                    
            </div>

            <div>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptFoo" OnItemCreated="rptFoo_ItemCreated" OnItemCommand="rpt_ItemCommand">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table id="TabRep"  class="DataRepeater">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>                                    
                                <th></th>                                     
                            </tr>                                
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                       SomeContent Here with controls
                    </tr>                        
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                </tbody>
                   </table>                                                     
                </FooterTemplate>                       
            </asp:Repeater> 
            <br/>                               
            </div>                                             
        </ContentTemplate>        
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And there.. It won't work. Controls of page outside the updatepanel lost theirs states and in debug mode, there is hundreds of "script blocks" generated..

[image: Screenshot VS]

My problem is that I don't really well understand how updatepanels are processing with javascript inside. So I need some advices from more experienced people. How can I make this updatepanel effective? What are thes hundreds of script blocks? I need to make the repeater more "Independent" from the rest of the page..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "Controls of page outside the updatepanel lost theirs states"? Can you be more specific?

Comment: If you want your application to be 'independent', get rid of asp.net controls and use/write own code. I love .net pages without many lines of viewstate data...

Comment: @Shadow Wizard; In the page (outside the repeater) is some checkBoxes controls. After update of the updatePanel all the checkboxes are unchecked..

Comment: How do you "update" the UpdatePanel exactly?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard; In the repeater Is a control who rebind the repeater with another datasource. It is a ImageButton who make a postBack. In the event I make a rptFoo.databind()

Comment: Interesting.. and if you ditch the UpdatePanel everything works fine without all the problems you described?

Comment: Yes. Everything works fine but the entire page is reloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these script block are here because you have a script block for each of you button

```
<input type="button" onclick="changebareme.."/>
```

It's not the update panel fault here.

A better approach would be to add a common css class to each of your button. Then with javascript select all of your button, and observe the click event on all of them.

Comment: Thanks I understand. But Why in the first load of the page these script block aren't there?

Comment: does your button have the onclick attribute ?

Comment: not in asp code. I set the OnclientClick in the ItemCreated's repeater event

Comment: @bAN your problem is resolved, my solution was the good one ?

Comment: yes,targeting with css class doesn't make these hundreds of script blocks.. I don't understand why they aren't present at the first load of the page but.. (And the "lost state" problem was independant.. He's solved too) thank you